# Get Comments on Properties

Tags: php

I was wondering if it is possible (easily) in PHP to get the comments on a class' properties e.g.:

```
/** 
* A test class
*
* @param int $TestId primary
* @param string $Name
* @param int $Age
* @param char $Gender
* @param date $DOB
*/
class Test extends DataObject {
    /**
    *
    * This is what I want
    *
    */
    public $TestId = 0;
    public $Name = "";
    public $Age = 0;
    public $Gender = "M";
    public $DOB = "";
}
```

I'm trying to see if I can get the comment for the property TestId easily?

Comment: Why does your class have `@param` in the doc block?

Comment: Look for reflection property in php

Comment: I was just playing around with it to see what I would get, I'm not concerned about the DocComment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`ReflectionProperty::getDocComment`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getdoccomment.php)

Something like:

```
$prop = new ReflectionProperty('Test', 'TestId');
print $prop->getDocComment();
```

There's no DocComment parser built in, but I wrote one [here](https://github.com/digitalnature/php-ref/blob/master/ref.php#L332) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for your offer but I've already used your example and am working on something a little differently.